# InitBinder is not called/Invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have radio  button on JSP Page.

```
<form:form  modelAttribute="obj" action="save">
    <form:radiobuttons path="person" items="${List}"/>

<form:button>Save</form:button>
</form:form>
```

List : List of person Objects
Obj :

```
Class obj{
     Person person;
     getter/setters
}
```

In that JSP, i have to append person when particular radio button selected.

On Controller side

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String postProcess(@ModelAttribute("obj") Obj obj,BindingResult error) {

            //processing
            return "anotherJsp";
        }


     @InitBinder
     public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, Locale locale, HttpServletRequest request) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Obj.class,"person", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        @Override
        public void setAsText(String text) {
            //processing for conversion of person object String to Person Object
            setValue(text);
        }
    });
}
```

Here i am using initbinder,because i am getting person object string from jsp...So i am getting binding exception **that can not convert from String to Person**.

InitBinder is called before when binding data to modelAttribute.Hence in initbinder i will conver string to Person object.

Here The main problem is That My **InitBinder in Not called/Invoked**.
please give me solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Please check whether it is getting called by putting breakpoints or debug statements.

Your model attribute is named "obj". But in propertyeditor you've used "person" as property path.

Please try using "obj" as propertyPath or remove that parameter and use this signature. 
[registerCustomEditor(Class requiredType, PropertyEditor propertyEditor)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/PropertyEditorRegistry.html#registerCustomEditor%28java.lang.Class,%20java.beans.PropertyEditor%29)

Hope it helps.

Comment: are you putting breakpoint at binder.registerCustomEditor(Ob.... or setValue(text);

Comment: I am Using System.Out in Method void setAsText()

Comment: put it as first line of public void initBinder(...) method. See if it is printing...

Comment: No,it is not printing

Answer (score 2):

Wild stab in the dark, is it importing the correct `@InitBinder` from `org.springframework.web.bind.annotation`?